# fn.apply is not a function - trying to create a Handlebars helper

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I create the file `app/helpers/test-helper.js`:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('test-helper', function() {
  return "Works!";
});
```

And in the template:

```
{{test-helper}}
```

And I get the above error in the console. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Instead of 'registerBoundHelper' try 'makeBoundHelper'. Like export default Ember.Handlebars.makeBoundHelper(function() {
  return "Works!";
});

Answer (score 1):

I wrestled with this for awhile myself. The trick is to use `makeBoundHelper` instead of `registerBoundHelper`

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Handlebars.makeBoundHelper('test-helper', function() {
  return "Works!";
});
```

[Here's a link to the source code](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/071b4bb6aad44100dc74ef8e1c79562e57038e7d/packages/ember-handlebars/lib/ext.js#L355)